# PHPUnit - Seleniumtest write in Database

Tags: database, selenium, phpunit

i would like to wrote my test-resulst into a database. Is there any way to do this without a skript?

My first idea was to get the json-log into the database, what are your experiences ?!

Comment: This may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887798/selenium-webdriver-with-sql-database/18888132#18888132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said why you need this, but if it's to keep track of your test-run history you could use Atlassian Bamboo. It will parse the output logs for you and provide many additional features such as re-running failed tests, emailing the results, scheduling, debug tickets etc.

There is a PHPUnit build task specifically designed for this purpose.